# How would I change this macro to start counting / pasting in row 29?

Tags: excel, vba

This macro copies a range from sheet1, and pastes it into the first available row (starting at A1) in sheet2. I've been trying to get it to start searching/pasting in A29, but haven't been able to get the semantics right.

Any input appreciated.

```
Sub copy2Database()
      
    ' This copies the Data to the Database
    
      Application.ScreenUpdating = False
      Dim copySheet As Worksheet
      Dim pasteSheet As Worksheet
    
      Set copySheet = Worksheets("DATA ENTRY")
      Set pasteSheet = Worksheets("REPORT")
    
      copySheet.Range("B23:M23").Copy
      pasteSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
      Application.CutCopyMode = False
      Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    End Sub
```

Comment: `pasteSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues` does this dynamically, so if you want to simple start on row 29... `pastesheet.cells(29,1).pastspecial xlpastevalues` may be it... it depends on if you'd be overwriting data, etc.

Comment: How do people run code without understanding it...

Comment: @findwindow  Press F5

Comment: If you understood `pasteSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues`, you wouldn't ask this question.

Comment: `Set cDest = pasteSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)` then `if cDest.Row<29 then set cDest = pasteSheet.Range("A29")` then `cDest.PasteSpecial xlPasteValues`

Comment: Are you choosing A29 because it is the next empty row?  Will that change with continued use?

Comment: A29 is constant, after pasting in this row, the next time the macro activated it will paste in A30

Answer (score 0):

Like this:

```vb
Sub copy2Database()
    Dim copySheet As Worksheet,pasteSheet As Worksheet, cDest As Range      
    
    
      Application.ScreenUpdating = False
      Set copySheet = Worksheets("DATA ENTRY")
      Set pasteSheet = Worksheets("REPORT")

      Set cDest = pasteSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)
      if cDest.Row < 29 then set cDest = pasteSheet.Range("A29") 'too high?
    
      'direct transfer is preferrable to copy/paste
      With copySheet.Range("B23:M23")
          cDest.Resize(.Rows.Count, .Columns.Count).Value= .Value
      End With

      Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: Can't exactly follow what this does, but I'm trying to start pasting in A29 , and when A29 is full, move to A30, etc, etc.